# Python: Writing a dictionary of lists to a .csv file with prefilled headers in non-consecutive locations

Tags: python, list, file, csv, dictionary

Here is my scenario:

I have created a dictionary of lists. I created this by importing .csv data and their column headers; i.e. the column headers are the keys, and their data are the items of the dictionary. The items of the dictionary are lists.

I only want to copy the items from the 1st .csv file to another 2nd .csv file, which has prefilled headers in it; i.e. I only want to copy the data under  a prefilled header in the 2nd file. The headers in the 2nd .csv file are not consecutive, i.e. the 'NAME' header may be in column A, while the 'DATE' header may be in column E.

My python script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import os.path
import re
import sys
import pdb
import csv


f =open('input.csv','rU')
reader = csv.reader(f)
headers = reader.next()
column = {}

for h in headers:
    column[h] = []

for row in reader:
    for h,v in zip(headers, row):
        column[h].append(v)

g = zip(*column['Name'])

resultFile = open("output.csv",'wb')
wr = csv.writer(resultFile, dialect='excel')
wr.writerow(g)
```

I can print out the dictionary items (which are lists) to the .csv file.

My problems are:

1) The lists are printing in a horizontal fashion (despite using the zip function)

2) I don't know how to print the vertical lists to a specific column location in the output.csv file; I haven't come across this problem in my research of answers on StackOverflow

3) Even if I do print the list, it writes over the predetermined header in the output.csv file.

I know there is a lot going on in this question, but I would really appreciate if someone can help and point me in the right direction.

Comment: There's no way to insert data in particular columns in a CSV file as such.  You should just read in the entire old CSV file (for instance, as a dict of lists like the one you have), insert your data in the right places, and then write out the entire new CSV file, including both the unmodified columns and the columns to which you added new data.

Answer (score 0):

If the two csv files have the same length (number of rows) and if you can use pandas:
   1. read in the two csv into pandas DataFrames,
   2. insert the columns from the 1st dataframe into the second, and
   3. write out the second dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('output.csv')

df2.insert(index, new_col_label, df1[column_label_in_df1])

df2.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```